# Core data, Modelo con 2 tablas con relación N:M

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa como ejercicio para entender el uso de `Core Data`. He creado 2 tablas ( `Persona` y `Libro` ) con relación `N:M` entre ellas. En el modelo creo las 2 tablas con sus atributos. Tengo una duda con las relaciones.

En relación  Persona relleno:
RelationShip: libros, Destination: Libro, Inverse: personas
En relación Libro relleno:
RelationShip: personas, Destination: Persona, Inverse: libros

Mis dudas son:

> ¿ Es correcto hacer una relación N:M con core data directamente entre
> 2 tablas ?
>
> ¿ No seria necesario hacer una tabla intermedia entre las
> tablas Persona y Libro para hacer dos  relaciones N:1 y N:1 ?
>
> ¿ Que pasa con la clave primaria y las claves foráneas ?
>
> ¿ Como se indican o cual es la manera de trabajar en el modelo de Core
> Data ?

Answer (score 1):

> ¿ No seria necesario hacer una tabla intermedia entre las tablas Persona y Libro para hacer dos relaciones N:1 y N:1 ?

Por lógica la relación N:M debe existir una tabla intermedia o sino sera un problema obtener los resultados que esperan.

> ¿ Que pasa con la clave primaria y las claves foráneas ? ¿ Como se indican o cual es la manera de trabajar en el modelo de Core Data ?

El `CoreData` no es una base de datos por lo tanto estas relaciones (lógicas) no ***corresponden*** en tu código, sirve para hacer persistencia dentro de tu código pero el que relaciona todo esto es la base de datos. Tu debes en la base de datos poder definir las `FK` y las `PK`, al tu crear un objeto dentro de tu proyecto `objective-c` ya estas creando relaciones (entre entidades), pero quien se encarga en verdad de verificar si estos datos son validos (en cuanto a relaciones lógicas de DB) es la base de datos.

Comment: Sobre las relaciones N:M he visto un tutorial en pdf donde mostraba  en core data 2 entidades unidas en una relación N:M pero no he llegado a a ver un ejemplo implementado en código con clases. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: En codigo puedes relacionar pero como te dije antes por entidades, son distintos contextos